# What service should I use for genomic and sequencing related analysis in Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, unix, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm a newbie in AWS computing.

I have a couple of terabyte sequencing data. 
From them, I'd like to process standard calculation like mapping the reads to a genome, etc.

First of all, I'd upload the data to amazon cloud. 
perform calculation by submitting several jobs on the cluster, 
so that it can be executed in parallel. I'm thinking of doing it
ala [LSF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_LSF) (bsub) or [PBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Batch_System)  (qsub).
Furthermore, there are other members of the team which would like to perform
a similar analysis on the AWS cloud.

I'm not sure how to do this. And what services should I use?

- Should I go to EC2 (with how many instances, etc)?
- Should I use S3 or EFS as data storage?
- What's the best way to send the data to the cloud? (UNIX-like SCP or aws)?
- How can I submit the job to multiple clusters?

Comment: There are just too many ways to answer this (good) question. AWS has a large toolchest, which could be combined in several different ways to achieve the goals, but some would cost more, some would be more flexible with respect to job changes, some would scale better, etc. I'm struggling to answer this without more constraints: how much $ do you have? what's the maximum expected job turnaround? how much sysadmin'ing are you willing to do? And so on.

Comment: @bishop: Thanks. Minimum sys admin, no problem with $, I can't answer on job turn around.

Comment: Ok, so based on your research of the AWS toolchest, what services dont't seem to fit and why? Like, maybe you read up on SQS and decided that it'd be nice to have the flexibility of a cluster that's always listening for new data, but you don't want the extra component because it requires additional administration.

Comment: @bishop: At the moment I have thought of the standard EC2 + EFS (pack). But two issues which I don't know which is the best way to solve in AWS. 1) Fast data transfer to cloud and 2) cluster base system ala LFS/PBS.

Comment: It's probably not optimal, but it's probably easier. The system optimal solution would use the native Amazon tools to map/reduce the jobs, but that would require a re-implementation of the LFS/PBS behavior. But if you're already familiar with LFS/PBS, and if you have no particular needs to deviate from the restrictions of LFS/PBS, then such a deep integration would likely not be the business optimal solution. The cost optimal solution is likely somewhere between the system- and business-optimal extremes.

Comment: AWS will consume data as fast as you can ship it to them. If you're at a research uni or a big corp, your outbound connection is probably fat enough to not have much worry over transfer time. Nevertheless, stream packetization could mitigate any transfer time worries.

Comment: Since you have the $ to spend, and you want to have minimum sysadmin, I think the best possible answer to your question is simple: engage a professional system designer to resolve the needs and blueprint a solution. Then you could either build the system, or have the professional build and manage it.

Comment: @bishop: Thanks for reply. 1) So what's amazon native job submission tool? So that I can execute multiple jobs in parallel. 2) What's the tool for `system packetization` you mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

Running LSF on AWS is possible and [well-documented](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/servicemanagement/sdi/spectrum-lsf/lsf_rc_for_aws.pdf). Basically you establish a vanilla EC2 cluster with a EFS backend and using LFS to consume your data and produce your output. Whether or not this will be absolutely the best architecture is debatable: AWS provides a whole toolchest that does what LSF does, are more deeply-integrated with each other, and likely have better performance per dollar. But, it would require rethinking a solution not-built around LSF, so the marginal cost of ECS+EFS may be worth it.

Getting your data onto the cluster should be straightforward and reasonably resistent to failures with `rsync`. As much as possible, *packetize* the data stream on your side, sending the smallest workable unit to the cluster at a time: this will get jobs going as fast as possible and will help make transmission more resilient to producer-side interruptions.

If you're using LSF as your job runner, the way you submit jobs to it is with a [standard LSF file](https://www2.cisl.ucar.edu/resources/computational-systems/yellowstone/using-computing-resources/running-jobs/platform-lsf-job-script-examples). A single EC2 could act as the "gateway", receiving job files and waiting until data streams are available. Alternatively, you might establish an AWS ELB (Load Balancer) to act as a front gateway, which would distribute that management work to all machines in the load-balancer. Or you could use SQS to hold the job definitions in stasis until the streams arrive, which would protect the job definitions from the loss of any particular EC2 instances.

On the other hand, you could use something like [Amazon Kinesis](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/streams/) to manage the incoming stream of data and run parallel jobs on it. This gets rid of the need for LFS, replacing it with an AWS toolchest: Kinesis (Firehose + Streams) + EMR (Elastic Map Reduce). This may not be desirable, though: you'd have to become familiar with those tools and might only save a few thousand.

In summary, LFS running EC2+EFS+ELB will work just fine. But, I can think of at least two other ways to do a similar thing using Amazon native tools. Each has its own pros and cons and would need to be considered. Since you have the budget and you want minimal system management, I'd suggest consulting with a professional designer to create a blueprint for the system that best fits your needs. Then you can either build and manage it, or have the professional do it.